# SDL can't create OpenGL windows

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

So here is my code:

```
void Game::init()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    _window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, _screenWidth, _screenHeight, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
}
```

This isn't working for some reason, but it works fine when I replace `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` with something like `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` or `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN`. It also doesn't work when I use `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN`. Anything I can do?

I'm using Kdevelop with Ubuntu, if that makes any difference.

**Update:**

So I figured out what was wrong. It turns out that when you build SDL with both GLX and EGL support, it always uses EGL. I had to compile it with `--disable-video-opengles`

Comment: What does `SDL_GetError()` say?

Comment: @TristanBrindle it says "No OpenGL support in video driver"... That's weird since I know my driver supports it.

Comment: well, that gives you your answer as to why it's not working... I'd check the installation of your video drivers, or the compilation flags of your SDL library

Comment: @TristanBrindle alright, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you most likely do support OpenGL, but which version? On Ubuntu, you can get this information by opening the terminal and typing `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`, which should give you the highest supported version. After that, you need to set those attributes in SDL. For example, to create an OpenGL 3.3 context:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
```

Make sure you do this before creating the context or the window.

Comment: I did try that. I know my graphics card supports OpenGL 3.5 but I think the problem is with SDL. All other 3D applications seem to be working fine including glxgear.

Comment: `SDL_Init` should be the [first SDL call in your program](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init).

Comment: @Kash there's no such version for OpenGL, the highest version in OpenGL 3 is 3.3

Comment: @Nasser Actually the highest version is 4.5. It says that on OpenGL's website: [OpenGL 4.5](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/current_version/)... Even my graphics card's website says that my model supports OpenGL 4.5 (I accidentally typed 3.5)

Comment: @Kash I think you might have misinterpreted my comment, I said "The highest version of **_OpenGL 3_** is 3.3", I am aware of OpenGL 4.5. Sorry for the confusion, maybe I could have phrased it more clearly.

Comment: @Nasser Oh okay. It's cool. I probably should have typed 4.5 the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have dual graphics setup like e.g. Nvidia Optimus? Maybe the reason why program cannot start propertly is that your driver dosen't switch from integrated Intel GPU to dedicated AMD or NVidia GPU.

I met with this issue at least once in my friend's laptop.

Comment: Actually no. I figured it out. The problem was with SDL

Comment: @Kash how did you fix it?